# Exception handling in C++ #4

Tags: c++

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

class A {
public:
    A() { cout << "HI" << endl; }
    ~A() { cout << "BYE" << endl; }
};

int main()
{
    try {
       A obj;
       throw obj;
    } catch(A a) {
       cout<<"Caught"<<endl;
    }
}
```

Output:
HI
BYE
Caught
BYE
BYE

Can someone explain why the constructor is not getting invoked when i create the new object (A a)? And also, why there are two times of destructor call after 'Caught'.

Comment: Catch by `const &` not by value.

Comment: `A a` is constructed using a copy constructor. That's why don't see the message from the default constructor.

Comment: @RSahu okay..but i did not understand why 2 times of destructor call?

Comment: `throw` creates the second `A` from `obj`. `catch(A a)` creates another copy from the thrown object.

Comment: @RSahu Now turn that into an answer.

Comment: @tambre, there are more than one duplicates if we search a little bit.

Comment: When instrument contructor/constructor, you have to instrument each one (copy/move constructor).

Comment: @RSahu I too thought that, but a quick search didn't bring up something. A deeper search will probably bring something up.

Comment: This isn't the problem, but do you really need the extra stuff that `std::endl` does? `'\n'` ends a line.

Comment: @PeteBecker No..but i have a habit of adding it :P